# Can i publish a book chapter independently?

Tags: phd, books, online-publication, bioinformatics

My question is can I publish a book chapter independently? I have completed my PhD and currently I am not enrolled anywhere, in this case can I publish it without approval of guide or institution?

Comment: Is a book chapter published on its own still a chapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not bound by any permissions. The Ph.D. thesis is your work and you have the copy-right. You might want to consider involving your Ph.D. advisor, because publishing papers even when based on Ph.D. thesis chapters is not trivial, but you have no obligation. In some disciplines (like mine / CS) it is customary to have the super-visor as a co-author, but this is not a requirement.

Comment: There are cases where the university owns the thesis copyright, see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/37796/17254